# symfony 2 fosuserbundle profiledit

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Can someone tell me the best way to edit in FosuserBundle only some field. I have my profile form from my user, I want some disabled fields, because I do not want that the user modify this field, but I want to show him the information. If I submit my form, I have an error.

This field must not be null

How can I edit only some fields, without validation constraint error from my entity in FosUserBundle?

Comment: You could use validation groups. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups

Answer (score 0):

You need add nullable=true to your fields in your User entity:

Example:

```
/**
 * @var String
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_first_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $userFirstName;
```

Comment: Thank, but if I add nullable=true in my entity then the validation form for register a new user   is break.